# Subtract two dates to give a timedelta

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get a value from one of my database values, which will be given by subtracting the purchase date from today's date.  I've written my code this way:

```
delta = datetime.now() - item.purchase_date
```

But this gives me this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'
```

If I use `datetime.datetime.now()` this doesn't work.  What am I missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to use [`date.today`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) or `datetime.now().date()` instead of `datetime.now`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today()
datetime.date(2010, 2, 10)
>>> datetime.datetime.now().date()
datetime.date(2010, 2, 10)
```

Comment: This gives me 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'

Comment: you have a mess with your imports it seems, I've posted an example of how it works.

Comment: datetime.now().date() works fine.  date.today works only from the python shell.

Comment: it works only from python shell because you're not importing it.